# Last item of ListView: Fab hides it

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, material-design

My problem is that i have a `ListView` with a floating action button attached to it. But the FAB hides a button if the list is at the very end. So I want to apply some free space but only to the last item of the list.

I'm using a simple adapter extending the `BaseAdapter`. So in getView, I could apply anything to the convertView if `position == getCount()-1`.

But how can I make that extra free space?

When I set padding via `convertView.setPadding`, to `56dp` the size does not increase, it just hides the elements in my ListView. If I use `LinearLayout.Layoutparams` and set margins, nothing happens at all.
So what can I do here?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Set bottom padding to the `ListView` itself. You have to set `android:clipToPadding="false"` to the `ListView` as well.

Comment: Does someone know how much the padding has to be? For a normal size FAB? How can we get that value?

Comment: @Blunderer, at least [56dp](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-floating-action-button)

Comment: Thanks! So 56dp + vertical_margin :)

Comment: This is a good solution, the problem with one is the scrollbar does not fill the height

Answer (score 1):

as well as Egor's approach, you can also use `ListView.setFooterView(View v)` to an inflated view that's as tall as your fab.